# Android studio sdk

Tags: android, android-studio

please guide me. I installed android studio, at first it said the sdk was installed, but I had not installed it, now when you want me to install it, it doesn't load, no matter what I did, it didn't work, please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrDv4.jpg)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/install#:~:text=Launch%20the%20Android%20Studio%20DMG,Studio%20settings%2C%20then%20click%20OK.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to uninstall Android Studio and try again. I'm not sure why the SDK Location would be blank after installing successfully.

Answer (score 4):

Try re-installing Android Studio

Comment: This worked for me. But I had to be sure to manually delete the Android directories after uninstalling, and then restart my machine. Previous reinstallations would not fix the issue.